# using regex to separate string in groups

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to parse string like this:

```
[NP Amanda Brumfield],[NP the estranged daughter][PP of][NP actor Billy Bob Thornton],[VP was found][ADJP guilty][PP of][VP aggravated][NP manslaughter][PP of][NP a child]
```

and in all this case recognise these groups:

```
[NP Amanda Brumfield][NP the estranged daughter][PP of][NP actor Billy Bob Thornton]
,
[ADJP guilty][PP of]
and
[NP manslaughter][PP of][NP a child]
```

In other words, it should use the string `[VP \w+]` to split the string.

How would I write regex for that?

Comment: What is the exact desired output? Also, what language are you using regex in?

Comment: why not use `\[VP .+?\]`?

Comment: You almost have written the right pattern, you only need to escape the opening square bracket, and eventually (depending of your regex flavour) to escape the closing square bracket. (as yate notices it)

Comment: i'm using php and output should be in array.

Comment: @user3700749: use `preg_split` and you are arrived: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php (keep in mind that `\w` doesn't contain space characters unlike `[\w\s]`.)

Comment: Use `$results = preg_split('/\[VP[^\]]*\]/i', $text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Casimir et Hippolyte mentions using `preg_split()`, which is correct. The following would split the given input the way you are requesting:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\[VP\s+(?:[^\]])+\]/', $input);
```

That pattern should allow for pretty much anything after the initial `VP` and one or more spaces prior to the closing `]`.  PHP should be fine with the non-capturing parens as well.